# Spinnaker rollout strategy Kubernetes vs Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, spinnaker

I am new to Spinnaker and when using the UI (with [Spinnaker for GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/spinnaker/spinnaker-for-gcp)), it says for rollout strategies

> Allow Spinnaker to associate each ReplicaSet deployed in this stage with one or more Services and manage traffic based on your selected rollout strategy options.

Does this mean that its rollout strategies are "only" Kubernetes-Replicaset based, but doesn't have support for, for example, Istio Traffic Management and Virtual Services? (or does the UI only offer limited option, compared to, say, an API)

Probably the same question can be asked for canary analysis?